# Active admin won't accept my route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I've some problems with getting the routes up n' running for my application.

### 1.

I want to be able to point active admin to http://admin.lvh.me:3000/
I tried using this code, but it only displays the index page.

```
# config/routes.rb
scope :admin, constraints: { subdomain: "admin" } do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(path: "/")
end

# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.default_namespace = :admin
```

The only url that works is http://admin.lvh.me:3000/admin
Is it possible to avoid `/admin`?

### 2.

Each exam in my application has many parts.
I want to add a parts button to each exam using this code.

```
# app/admin/exams.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Exam do
  # ...
  index do
    column :actions do |exam|
      link_to "Part", admin_exam_parts_path(exam)
    end

    default_actions
  end
  # ...
end
```

The problem is that `admin_exam_parts_path` doesn't exist.

```
# config/routes.rb
scope :admin, constraints: { subdomain: "admin" } do
  resources :exams do
    resources :parts
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(path: "/")
end
```

`rake routes | grep /admin/exams/:exam_id/parts` doesn't return anything.
What I'm I doing wrong?

I'm running

- active admin 0.5.1
- rails 3.2.12
- ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Any workaround so far ?

Comment: It looks like you don't need add your own custom admin routes. Instead you just define the relation within the (in my case) `app/admin/parts.rb`. Adding `belongs_to :exam` would in other words solve the problem.

Comment: Regarding the 1st item, did you manage to remove the /admin ?

Comment: No, I didn't manage to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem i have this on my routes.rb

```
root to: "admin/dashboard#index"
```

After resources and before devise_for, and works very fine!.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

"admin" is the default namespace for all resources.

you can turn off a resources namespace explicitly in the registration block like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Exam, :namespace => false  do
  ...
end
```

as far as you `has_many: :parts` association, can you post the code for your registration block for `Parts`?  There are several ways I might set up this relationship depending on what I was trying to accomplish.  So the more context you can give me, the better